# Group by unlike values

Tags: sql, grouping

I'm trying to create a report that shows line counts based on the report type. I'm grouping on report type, but some report types have specific names that I want combined under one listing.

For example:  `Urgent Care` reports can have a type of `Urgent Care`, `SD494`, `SD510`, `SD546` and multiple others.  I would like all the `SD###` to show up just under `Urgent Care` rather than a separate listing.  Same with `OP Notes`, they can be `OP Note`, `SD805`, `polysomnography`, etc.  I would like those just under `OP Notes`, but all in one report.  I currently have about 20 different reports that I can run individually for each report type.

How can I accomplish this task?

```
declare @officeID int = 93;
declare @startDate datetime = '6/01/2015';
declare @endDate datetime = '07/01/2015';

select (r.reporttype),  
sum(cast(round(r.transcriptionlinecount,2) as decimal(8,2))) as "Bill Lines", 
(cast(round(sum(r.transcriptionlinecount) * .13,2) as decimal(8,2))) as "Amount"
from rptlinecountinfo as r
join dictation as d on d.dictationID = r.dictationID
where 
d.officeID = @officeID 
and r.finishedtime between @startDate and @endDate
and (d.dictationStatus != 'D' and d.dictationStatus != 'Q')
group by r.reporttype
```

Here are the results: (I've added a numbering column just so it isn't in paragraph form)

1. ASC Pre-OP Consult  1848.96 240.36
2. Audiology Report    4403.73 572.48
3. Cardiac Cath    452.26  58.79
4. Colon 539 Op Note   117.49  15.27
5. Colonoscopy - OP Note   118.11  15.35
6. Colonoscopy-Op Note 54.88   7.13
7. Consult 3219.01 418.47
8. CPAP Titration  1802.61 234.34
9. Discharge Summary   5259.79 683.77
10. EGD - Op Note   316.66  41.17
11. EGD 537 Op Note 178.71  23.23
12. EGD-Op Note 194.75  25.32
13. Electrophysiology Report    1679.79 218.37
14. ER Admit    39402.45    5122.32
15. ER Format   150642.53   19583.53
16. ERCP-Op Note    108.88  14.15
17. Hospital Course 5344.91 694.84
18. Multidisciplinary Oncology  272.38  35.41
19. OP Note 32437.7 4216.9
20. Op Note - SD698 57.66   7.5
21. Pain Clinic Letter  32.71   4.25
22. Pain Clinic Report  6.71    0.87
23. Pain Clinic SD1020  37.75   4.91
24. PHP Discharge Summary   336.81  43.79
25. PM Inpatient Consultation   1602.96 208.38
26. Polysomnography 2466.16 320.6
27. Pre-OP Consult  30812.45    4005.62
28. SD288 Initial Injury    6398.55 831.81
29. SD289 Follow Up 2893.45 376.15
30. SD289 Follow-Up 2498.36 324.79
31. SD488 OP Note   48.86   6.35
32. SD496 - Urgent Care 32.34   4.2
33. SD503 - Urgent Care 40.17   5.22
34. SD504 - Urgent Care 40.54   5.27
35. SD509 - Urgent Care 75.95   9.87
36. SD541 - Urgent Care 193.14  25.11
37. SD594 - Urgent Care 42.89   5.58
38. SD606 - Urgent Care 43.31   5.63
39. Sleep - MSLT    85.53   11.12
40. Sleep Letter    4505.21 585.68
41. Sleep Report    25243.47    3281.65
42. Speech Report   357.73  46.5
43. STAT Discharge Summary  1148.06 149.25
44. Surgical Hospitalist Clinic Note    1961.71 255.02
45. Urgent Care 30221.61    3928.81
46. Urgent Care - SD494 227.37  29.56
47. Urgent Care - SD496 37.17   4.83
48. Urgent Care - SD503 202.07  26.27
49. Urgent Care - SD504 117.74  15.31
50. Urgent Care - SD508 67.97   8.84
51. Urgent Care - SD509 60.1    7.81
52. Urgent Care - SD510 33.57   4.36
53. Urgent Care - SD541 47.4    6.16
54. Urgent Care - SD546 27.77   3.61
55. Urgent Care - SD594 40.17   5.22

Comment: Can you post the results you're getting with the current query?

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS, you may be able to gather the unlike values using a `case`/`when` statement into a groupable field. That is, a field named "report_group", where values "x", "y", "z" have a value of "Group1"; values "a", "b", "c" have a value of "Group2", etc. It's a pain to maintain--it'd be better to adjust your data model to include a group field. But that would likely require app changes as well, which I recognize can be difficult to propagate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases (you didn't specify yours), just use a `CASE` statement to group the values the way you want them, and then use that same `CASE` statement in both your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

To get you started:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN r.reporttype LIKE 'SD%' THEN 'Urgent Care'
            WHEN r.reporttype IN ('OP Note','SD805','polysomnography') THEN 'OP Notes'
            ELSE r.reporttype END AS reporttype,
sum(cast(round(r.transcriptionlinecount,2) as decimal(8,2))) as "Bill Lines", 
(cast(round(sum(r.transcriptionlinecount) * .13,2) as decimal(8,2))) as "Amount"
from rptlinecountinfo as r
join dictation as d on d.dictationID = r.dictationID
where 
d.officeID = @officeID 
and r.finishedtime between @startDate and @endDate
and (d.dictationStatus != 'D' and d.dictationStatus != 'Q')
group by CASE WHEN r.reporttype LIKE 'SD%' THEN 'Urgent Care'
              WHEN r.reporttype IN ('OP Note','SD805','polysomnography') THEN 'OP Notes'
              ELSE r.reporttype END
```

I should warn you that the above logic in the `CASE` statement is already broken. The reason is that there is an inconsistency in your requirement.

On the one hand, you say that all report types that follow this pattern `SD###` should be mapped to `Urgent Care`.  But what about `SD805`? You say you want that one to be mapped to `OP Notes`, but it's also valid as `Urgent Care` as per your specification.  So you'll have to figure what it is you really want in this case.  If you only have that one exception, then maybe all you need to do is reorder then conditions so that the exceptional case is checked first.

Also, to represent your `SD###` requirement, I translated that to the very standard `LIKE 'SD%'`, which may also match patterns like `SD5`, or `SD`, or `SDDFGDFG`.  If this is not what you want, then look for the appropriate regex statement for your database, and change it to that.